# Securely save credentials to Gmail account for SMTP

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, asp.net-core, smtp

```
var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
```

Hi guys. In my website, I would like to use SMTP to send emails to users. The main problem is with the security of my credentials. How can I securely store my email and password and use them while sending emails to users? I’ve thought about `Web.Config` file but it’s not still secure. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: You should really elaborate more the question like which .net framework are you using?. Moving on, if you're using dot net core you can take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=windows

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Core doesn't use web.config, so that's out right off the bat. In general, you want to use a configuration provider so that the configuration is at least external to the application (i.e. not hard-coded). Out of the available providers, the only truly secure (i.e. encrypted) option is Azure Key Vault, which can be used with out without actually hosting your app in Azure. It should be noted that while minimal, there is a cost to that. A good compromise is usually environment variables. While they exist as plain text (not encrypted), they're local to the server you're deploying to, and therefore only visible to someone that can actually login to that server. If you get a sysadmin account compromised, then your secrets are exposed, but technically, at that point, you're borked regardless.